# How can I find out exactly what caused the wake-up of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I had this problem once before when I was running Windows 7. I don't remember which device was causing the insomnia but I remember running the command `powercfg -lastwake` which told me exactly which device caused the wake-up. But the same command under Windows 10 only gives me this useless response:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
Wake Source Count - 0
```

Any other commands I could use to find out exactly what caused the wake-up?

Comment: You could check out the task scheduler as a start, it will show you last run times for specific items that started up, and may provide some clues.  Also the event logs.